# Collision Detection Not Working in SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am stuck on this for several hours now which seems like a very simple task. I have an SKSpriteNode call Ball which is declared below:

```
-(instancetype) initWithType:(BallType) ballType
{
    if(ballType == UserBall) {

        self = [super initWithImageNamed:USER_BALL_IMAGE];
        self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = BBPhysicsCategoryUserBall;
        self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = BBPhysicsCategoryRedBall | BBPhysicsCategoryWorld;
        self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
    }

    // setup physical aspects of the ball
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:self.size.width/2];
    self.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;
    self.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;

    return self;

}
```

I create another SKSpriteNote "redBall" as below:

```
  SKSpriteNode *redBall = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:RED_BALL_IMAGE];
        redBall.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = BBPhysicsCategoryRedBall;
        redBall.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = BBPhysicsCategoryUserBall;
        redBall.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:redBall.size.width/2];
        redBall.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;

        redBall.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2 , self.size.height/4);

        [self addChild:redBall];

        [redBall.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.5)];
```

My GameScene inherits from SKScene and implements the SKPhysicsContactDelegate protocol. I assign the contactDelegate as follows:

```
-(void) setupPhysicsWorld {

    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
    self.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;

    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = BBPhysicsCategoryWorld;
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

}
```

But for some reason the didBeginContact is NEVER CALLED!!! I am going crazy as why it is not being called?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(instancetype) initWithType:(BallType) ballType
{
    if(ballType == UserBall) {

        self = [super initWithImageNamed:USER_BALL_IMAGE];
        self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = BBPhysicsCategoryUserBall;
        self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = BBPhysicsCategoryWorld;
        self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
    }

    // setup physical aspects of the ball
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:self.size.width/2];
    self.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;
    self.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;

    return self;

}

  SKSpriteNode *redBall = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:RED_BALL_IMAGE];
        redBall.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = BBPhysicsCategoryRedBall;
        redBall.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = BBPhysicsCategoryUserBall;
        redBall.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:redBall.size.width/2];
        redBall.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;

        redBall.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2 , self.size.height/4);

        [self addChild:redBall];

        [redBall.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.5)];
 you are setting  redBall.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask  twice
```